# Silver greasy coating on disk brakes

Tags: brakes, rotor, grease

Today I came in to the bike mechanic to align my disk brake calipers and they came out with the disk brakes covered in a silver lubricant (they said that this was especially for disk brakes)

They failed to explain why they put this on, what it was and I felt a decrease in braking power after.

Can anyone possibly deduct what this is?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  A picture might help; is this on the rotor?  Are you sure it's lubricant?  It seems strange to apply a lubricant to any external part of a brake.

Comment: Possibly not lubricant. Copper slip is sometimes used between pad  and piston to thermally connect and prevent vibration/noise. 

You need to explain what “covered in” means in objective terms.

Comment: @WarrenBurton There are similar "brake silencer" products made specifically for brakes which look similar to antiseize. Might be that too.